# Reference values of a dynamic table from worksheet A to a table in worksheet B

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table (t1) in worksheet A, which gets new entries, every time we update the powerquery.

Now I want to use 1 column (name) of t1 in a table (t2) in worksheet B.

How do I manage go get those information without using VBA?

I tried to reference it by

```
=worksheetA!A1
=worksheetA!A2
...
```

but with this method I need to update t2 manually.

I also tried to get the information with

```
=t1[@name]]
```

But this doesn't give me all entries back, as well as doesn't work if its inside of t2.

It works when outside of the table but still not as intended.

DO you guys have any idea?

Comment: What happens if you type `=t1[name]` (without `@` because that means `at the same row number`)

Comment: If I type 

```=t1[name]
```

it still gives me back the value from the same row number

Answer (score 0):

In older Excel you can do this using the following formula: `=IFERROR(INDEX(t1[name],ROW(A1),),"")`
copied down.

It indexes `t1[name]` and starts at row 1 `ROW(A1)` of that indexed range. If you copie it down it'll show the 2nd row, etc. If you're out of rows to reference against, the IFERROR will prevent an error message and will show a blank value.

In Office 365 you can simply type `=t1[name]`

Comment: Yeah, that worked really nice. Ty! 
But if I understand correctly, I have to use that formula for all cells in my column A (under the header name). 

So I have a bunch of table entries with no values in them. 

Is there a way for Excel to detect if there is a new entry in t1 and add it to t2?

Comment: You could use power query or update your Excel to Microsoft 365

Comment: And depending on what you want to do with the values, you might be able to do it in the original table itself.